# How to query a denormalized BigQuery table to output nested and repeated fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some data being regularly loaded into a BigQuery database. Each row represents the movement of a piece of inventory as part of fulfilling an order.

The related order and "order_product" information are embedded as nested records within the row.

Here's an example of some of the rows:

```
|----------|----------|----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|---------------------------------|
| move_id  | quantity | order.id | order_product.id | order_product.quantity | order_product.price |      item_reference_number      |
|----------|----------|----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|---------------------------------|
|    1     |    1     |     1    |         1        |            1           |           5         |               ABC               |
|----------|----------|----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|---------------------------------|
|    2     |    1     |     1    |         2        |            1           |           7         |               DEF               |
|----------|----------|----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|---------------------------------|
|    3     |    1     |     1    |         2        |            1           |           7         |               XYZ               |
|----------|----------|----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|---------------------------------|
```

As you can see, the table shows three stock movements. All associated to Order 1.

Order 1 consists of one order_product 1 and one order_product 2. Order_product 1 consists of one stock movement, move_id 1 for item ABC.

Order_product 2 consists of two stock movements, move_id 2 for item DEF, and move_id 3 for item XYZ.

How can I write a query to translate this data into a table with proper nested/repeated fields? In other words, I would like the data to look like this:

```
|-----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|
| order_id  | order_product.id | order_product.quantity | order_product.price |      stock_move.id     | stock_move.quantity | stock_move.item_reference_number |
|-----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|
|     1     |         1        |            1           |          5          |            1           |           1         |                ABC               |
|           |------------------|------------------------|---------------------|------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|
|           |         2        |            1           |          7          |            2           |           1         |                DEF               |
|           |                  |                        |                     |------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|
|           |                  |                        |                     |            3           |           1         |                XYZ               |
|-----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|
```

I've been reading [this post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/exploring-a-powerful-sql-pattern-array-agg-struct-and-unnest-b7dcc6263e36), which seems to indicate that `ARRAY_AGG` could be what I need, but I can't figure out how to use it correctly for my problem.

I think my problem is I'm struggling to reduce the nested order_products down to one row for each one, while populating the correct nested/repeated stock moves for each order_product.

Is it even possible to do what I'm asking? I really appreciate any help to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT order_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(product ORDER BY product.id) order_product,
  ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(stock_move) stock_move
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, 
    STRUCT(order_product.id, order_product.quantity, order_product.price) product,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(move_id AS id, quantity AS quantity, item_reference_number AS item_reference_number)) stock_move
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY order_id, order_product.id, order_product.quantity, order_product.price
  ORDER BY order_product.id -- <-- this is to make sure stock_move array is ordered as in your expected output  - but really not needed here
)
GROUP BY order_id
```

when applied to your sample data  - above produces result as below

[image]

I am not sure if this is exactly what you meant as your examples are still ambiguous a little, but hope this gives you an idea

Also please note: I assumed that `order.id` in your example is actually `order_id` otherwise it does not make much sense, but I can be wrong with this (as I mentioned your example is still ambiguous "a little")

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is supposed to be `order.id`. The order is a nested resource for the row. In reality there are other fields on the order that I would like to preserve, for example, `order.source`, but I wasn't showing them in order to simplify the example. Does that change anything? Also, is there any way you can add an explanation for what the different pieces of the query are doing? I'm new to this and would like to understand the reason for each piece.

Comment: What did you mean by saying the `ORDER BY order_product.id` isn't actually necessary? I am finding that without that, the stock moves are not associated to the correct order product, but I am confused why that is. I think I am missing something fundamental about the nested fields. Aren't those stock moves nested within their order_product rows? So shouldn't they just automatically stay with wherever the order_product row goes?

Comment: scratch this extra comment - i should of removed this one when posted answer. obviously w/o order by it does not produce expected result and that is why i have it there

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's not obvious to me though. Why does it need ORDER BY? Aren't those stock move rows nested within their parent order_products? Also, is the ORDER BY needed in the outer queries ARRAY_AGG function? That one seems to make no difference.

Comment: as I mentioned  - examples in your question are ambiguous and it is not clear exactly what you expect. so I tried to get as close to your expected result as i could (even visually) so that is why I added order so it make output in order of product

Comment: I think I realized what I'm trying to ask. I think I need the output to contain an array of `order.order_product.stock_move`. In other words, `stock_move` needs to be a nested repeated field of the order_product. It shouldn't be on the top-level with the `order.` Does that make sense?

Comment: I think - it is. so you should post new question with all related details (please be as detailed as you can describing your input and expected output) so we will be able to help you there :o)

Answer (score 1):

Will the following SQL meet your expectations?

I created stock_move in the order_product way.

```
WITH original_table AS (
    SELECT 1 AS move_id, 1 AS quantity, STRUCT(1 AS id) AS `order`, STRUCT(1 AS id, 1 AS quantity, 5 AS price) AS order_product, "ABC" AS item_reference_number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS move_id, 1 AS quantity, STRUCT(1 AS id) AS `order`, STRUCT(2 AS id, 1 AS quantity, 7 AS price) AS order_product, "DEF" AS item_reference_number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS move_id, 1 AS quantity, STRUCT(1 AS id) AS `order`, STRUCT(2 AS id, 1 AS quantity, 7 AS price) AS order_product, "XYZ" AS item_reference_number
),

t1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        move_id,
        quantity,
        `order`.id AS order_id,
        order_product.id AS order_product_id,
        order_product.quantity AS order_product_quantity,
        order_product.price AS order_product_price,
        item_reference_number
    FROM original_table
),

t2 AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        order_product_id,
        order_product_quantity,
        order_product_price,
        ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(move_id, quantity, item_reference_number) ORDER BY move_id) AS stock_move
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY order_id, order_product_id, order_product_quantity, order_product_price
),

t3 AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(order_product_id AS id, order_product_quantity AS quantity, order_product_price AS price, stock_move) ORDER BY order_product_id) AS order_product
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY order_id
)

SELECT * FROM t3
```

```
|-----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|------------------------------------------------|
| order_id  | order_product.id | order_product.quantity | order_product.price | order_product.stock_move.move_id | order_product.stock_move.quantity | order_product.stock_move.item_reference_number |
|-----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|------------------------------------------------|
|     1     |         1        |            1           |          5          |              1                   |           1                       |                ABC                             |
|           |------------------|------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|------------------------------------------------|
|           |         2        |            1           |          7          |              2                   |           1                       |                DEF                             |
|           |                  |                        |                     |----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|------------------------------------------------|
|           |                  |                        |                     |              3                   |           1                       |                XYZ                             |
|-----------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|------------------------------------------------|
```